# get animal names from text file into List Of String

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file with about 800 animal names! how can I make a (List Of String) read from that text file? each animal name is in line by line, this is what im using just for 4

```
    Dim animalsList As New List(Of String)() From
    {
        "dog",
        "cat",
        "bird",
        "monkey"
    }
```

Comment: This will be quite large in memory.  Can you use a database instead?

Comment: @ps2goat no I cant use a database...

Comment: @ps2goat 800 animal names will be quite large in memory? Why's that?

Comment: @ps2goat: If 800 animal names is too large, we must be in the 80's!

Comment: It depends on the usage.  E.g., I wouldn't want to store something like this as a global lookup.  Once that starts, it's only a matter of time before the rest of the code follows suit.  It's all about context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(streams the lines) or [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (creates an array of all lines):

```
Dim animalsList As List(Of String) = File.ReadLines(path).ToList()
```

Comment: @crush: doesn't make a great difference if you want to create a collection of all lines anyway.

Comment: Wait a second, it's only 800 animal names.